# How to inhibit ClickOnce-Update promt?

Tags: c#, clickonce

Is there any possibility to update a ClickOnce application automatically without confirming?

Thank you very much.

ClickOnce prompt:

http://img.7pics.info/update_1c2.png

Comment: Are you building your ClickOnce application manifests using Visual Studio or using the mage/mageui utilities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the updates dialog, set the minimum version to the same version number you are deploying. This will make it a 'forced update' and won't ask the user, but will just install it.